# Не показывает страницу при деплое heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, развертывание, heroku

В девелопменте все работает нормально. При деплое на Хероку все тоже работает нормально - кроме страницы shipments/new (форма создания Shipment) - на ней Хероку выдает заглушку "We're sorry, but something went wrong." Assets precompile уже пробовал.  При выполнении "heroku run rake db:migrate" выдает следующее:

```
Running rake db:migrate on guarded-citadel-14552... up, run.9678
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   (2.9ms)  SELECT t2.oid::regclass::text AS to_table, a1.attname AS column, a2.attname AS primary_key, c.conname AS name, c.confupdtype AS on_update, c.confdeltype AS on_delete
FROM pg_constraint c
JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
WHERE c.contype = 'f'
  AND t1.relname = 'expectations'
  AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
ORDER BY c.conname

   (2.4ms)  SELECT t2.oid::regclass::text AS to_table, a1.attname AS column, a2.attname AS primary_key, c.conname AS name, c.confupdtype AS on_update, c.confdeltype AS on_delete
FROM pg_constraint c
JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
WHERE c.contype = 'f'
  AND t1.relname = 'friendships'
  AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
ORDER BY c.conname

   (2.5ms)  SELECT t2.oid::regclass::text AS to_table, a1.attname AS column, a2.attname AS primary_key, c.conname AS name, c.confupdtype AS on_update, c.confdeltype AS on_delete
FROM pg_constraint c
JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
WHERE c.contype = 'f'
  AND t1.relname = 'shipment_expectations'
  AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
ORDER BY c.conname

   (2.7ms)  SELECT t2.oid::regclass::text AS to_table, a1.attname AS column, a2.attname AS primary_key, c.conname AS name, c.confupdtype AS on_update, c.confdeltype AS on_delete
FROM pg_constraint c
JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
WHERE c.contype = 'f'
  AND t1.relname = 'shipments'
  AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
ORDER BY c.conname

   (2.4ms)  SELECT t2.oid::regclass::text AS to_table, a1.attname AS column, a2.attname AS primary_key, c.conname AS name, c.confupdtype AS on_update, c.confdeltype AS on_delete
FROM pg_constraint c
JOIN pg_class t1 ON c.conrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_class t2 ON c.confrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = c.conkey[1] AND a1.attrelid = t1.oid
JOIN pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = c.confkey[1] AND a2.attrelid = t2.oid
JOIN pg_namespace t3 ON c.connamespace = t3.oid
WHERE c.contype = 'f'
  AND t1.relname = 'users'
  AND t3.nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
ORDER BY c.conname
```

Деплой:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 253 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Using minitest 5.8.4
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using CFPropertyList 2.3.2
remote:        Using rake 11.1.2
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
remote:        Using rack 1.6.4
remote:        Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
remote:        Using arel 6.0.3
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.7
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Using execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.1
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using excon 0.49.0
remote:        Using formatador 0.2.5
remote:        Using multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Using ipaddress 0.8.3
remote:        Using xml-simple 1.1.5
remote:        Using inflecto 0.0.2
remote:        Using sass 3.4.22
remote:        Using tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.0
remote:        Using subexec 0.2.3
remote:        Using pg 0.17.1
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Using faker 1.4.2
remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using fission 0.5.0
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
remote:        Using mime-types 3.0
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using warden 1.2.6
remote:        Using puma 2.11.1
remote:        Using sprockets 3.6.0
remote:        Using fog-core 1.37.0
remote:        Using uglifier 2.5.3
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using mini_magick 3.8.0
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.2
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.2
remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.0
remote:        Using mail 2.6.4
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Using fog-json 1.0.2
remote:        Using fog-xml 0.1.2
remote:        Using fog-local 0.3.0
remote:        Using fog-vmfusion 0.1.0
remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.2
remote:        Using climate_control 0.0.3
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.2.3
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using fog-aliyun 0.1.0
remote:        Using fog-brightbox 0.10.1
remote:        Using fog-sakuracloud 1.7.5
remote:        Using fog-serverlove 0.1.2
remote:        Using fog-softlayer 1.1.0
remote:        Using fog-storm_on_demand 0.1.1
remote:        Using fog-atmos 0.1.0
remote:        Using fog-aws 0.9.2
remote:        Using fog-dynect 0.0.3
remote:        Using fog-ecloud 0.3.0
remote:        Using fog-google 0.1.0
remote:        Using fog-powerdns 0.1.1
remote:        Using fog-profitbricks 0.0.5
remote:        Using fog-radosgw 0.0.5
remote:        Using fog-riakcs 0.1.0
remote:        Using fog-terremark 0.1.0
remote:        Using fog-voxel 0.1.0
remote:        Using fog-xenserver 0.2.3
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Using activejob 4.2.2
remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.2
remote:        Using carrierwave 0.10.0
remote:        Using cocaine 0.5.8
remote:        Using actionview 4.2.2
remote:        Using paperclip 4.3.6
remote:        Using fog 1.36.0
remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.2
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.2
remote:        Using railties 4.2.2
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Using responders 2.1.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.0.3
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.2
remote:        Using rails 4.2.2
remote:        Using turbolinks 2.3.0
remote:        Using devise 3.5.6
remote:        Using foundation-icons-sass-rails 3.0.0
remote:        Bundle complete! 27 Gemfile dependencies, 99 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (0.56s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
remote:        To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
remote:        ruby '2.2.4'
remote:        # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> web
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 53.4M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v20
remote:        https://guarded-citadel-14552.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/guarded-citadel-14552.git
   292c771..2be75f3  master -> master
```

Модель Shipment:

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friendship

  has_many :shipment_expectations
  has_many :expectations, through: :shipment_expectations

  validates :image, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "200x333>", medium: "900x1500>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  enum days: {"3": 3, "7": 7, "14": 14, 
                                              "30": 30}
end
```

Форма Shipment которую не показывает:

```
<%= form_for(@shipment, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>

      <% if @shipment.errors.any? %>
        <div class="alert callout">
          <h3>Запрос не был отправлен из за следующих ошибок:</h3>
          <ul>
          <% @shipment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="7u 12u$(xsmall)">
            <small>
              Добавьте фотографию пересылаемого предмета.
            </small>
            <br/>
            <%= f.file_field :image, id: "FileUpload", class: "show-for-sr" %>
        </div>

        <div class="7u 12u$(xsmall)" style="padding-top: 25px;">
          <small>
            Выбрите получателя из списка друзей или заполните данные вручную.
            ( <%= link_to "Добавить друга?", my_friends_path %> )
          </small>
                    <div class="select-wrapper">
                        <%= f.select :friend_id, user.friendships.map{ |friendship| 
                         [friendship.friend.name, friendship.id] }, 
                         prompt: "Выберите получателя из списка друзей" %>
                    </div>
          <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Фамилия Имя Отчество" %>
          <%= f.text_field :adress, placeholder: "Почтовый адрес получателя" %>
          <div class="select-wrapper">
            <%= f.select :days, Shipment.days.keys, 
                                prompt: "Выберите срок доставки" %>
          </div>
        </div>

            <div class="7u 12u$(xsmall)" style="padding-top: 30px;">
          <%= f.submit "Готово!", class: "button special2" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Смотрите логи после запроса.

Comment: А где они находятся?

Comment: За `heroku logs`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло - ляп был связан с ассоциациями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запусти в терминале

```
heroku logs --tail
```

Отображение логов realtime.